# Método NotNull() do Fluent Validation não funciona

Tags: .net, validação, fluentvalidation

Olá!

Desenvolvi algumas validações para registro de usuário que seguem:

```
using FluentValidation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SaleTheaterTickets.Models.ViewModelValidators
{
    public class RegisterViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterViewModel>
    {
        public RegisterViewModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Email)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Informe o e-mail")
                .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Digite um e-mail válido (ana@gmail.com)");
            RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Informe a senha")
                .Length(6, 20).WithMessage("Senha deve ter no mínimo 6 e no máximo 20 caractéres")
                .Must(RequireDigit).WithMessage("Senha deve ter pelo menos 1 número")
                .Must(RequiredLowerCase).WithMessage("Senha deve ter pelo menos 1 caracter minúsculo")
                .Must(RequireUppercase).WithMessage("Senha deve ter pelo menos 1 caracter maiúsculo")
                .Must(RequireNonAlphanumeric).WithMessage("Digite pelo menos 1 caracter especial (@ ! & * ...)");
            RuleFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
                .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Confirme a senha")
                .Equal(x => x.Password).WithMessage("Senhas não conferem");
        }

        private bool RequireDigit(string password)
        {
            if (password.Any(x => char.IsDigit(x)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool RequiredLowerCase(string password)
        {
            if (password.Any(x => char.IsLower(x)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool RequireUppercase(string password)
        {
            if (password.Any(x => char.IsUpper(x)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private bool RequireNonAlphanumeric(string password)
        {
            //if (password.Any(x => char.IsSymbol(x)))
            //{
            //    return true;
            //}
            //return false;

            if (Regex.IsMatch(password, "(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Meu problema está sendo o seguinte; os métodos que são chamados na propriedade `password` com o Must não aceitam valor nulo. Quando coloco algo vazio na senha, lá no formulário parece que o NotEmpty não funciona, porque ele deixa passar vazio e não mostra a mensagem, acabando dando o seguinte erro no servidor:

Ocorreu uma exceção não tratada ao processar a solicitação.

> ArgumentNullException: Value não pode ser nulo. (Parâmetro 'fonte')
> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException (argumento ExceptionArgument)
> Pilha Consulta Cookies Cabeçalhos Encaminhamento
> ArgumentNullException: Value não pode ser nulo. (Parâmetro 'fonte')
> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException (argumento ExceptionArgument)
> System.Linq.Enumerable.Any  (IEnumerable  source, Func <TSource, bool> predicado)    SaleTheaterTickets.Models.ViewModelValidators.RegisterViewModelValidator.RequireDigit (string senha) em RegisterViewModelValidator.cs+
> if (password.Any (x => char.IsDigit (x)))
> FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions + <> c__DisplayClass21_0 <T, TProperty>.  b__0 (T x, TProperty val) em DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs
> FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions + <> c__DisplayClass22_0 <T, TProperty>.  b__0 (T x, TProperty val, PropertyValidatorContext propertyValidatorContext) em DefaultValidatorExtensions.cs

Este erro acontece exatamente porque os métodos abaixo não aceitam valor nulo - também não sei bem porque. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender porque o NotEmpty não barra isso? Porque na propriedade Email e ConfirmPassword funciona.